# how to open MatDialog and pass MatDialogRef

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developping an angular application. I try to use MatDialog to open a dialog box and try to be able to close it

I open the dialog this way

```
openDialog(event) {
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
  dialogConfig.position = {
    top:  bottom + 'px',
    right: '0px'
  };
  dialogConfig.width = '50%';
  dialogConfig.height = '590px';

  this.dialog.open(UserDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

  dialogRef.beforeClose().subscribe((result: string) => {
    console.log('RIght before close,', result);
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
  });
}
```

I inject MatDialogRef in the constructor of UserDialogComponent:

```
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
      console.log("Constructor UserDialogComponent START");
      console.log(dialogRef);
      this.dialogRef = dialogRef;
      console.log("Constructor UserDialogComponent END");
     }
```

And to close the dialog box, I use this function

```
  close() {
    console.log(this.dialogRef);
    console.log('CLOSE CLICKED');
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
```

But this.dialogRef is an empty object and I receive the following error when I call this function

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.dialogRef.close is not a function"
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: I am really confused. I removed it, but I have still the error

Comment: Can you share the code of the dialog component?

Comment: Yeah now try deleting that beforeClose code. It must work fine

Answer (score 1):

you put me on the trail

There was this code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-dialog',
  templateUrl: './user-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-dialog.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_RADIO_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { color: 'accent' }},
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
  ]
})
export class UserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
```

I removed

```
{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
```

And now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

remove this `this.dialogRef = dialogRef;` and try

```
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
      console.log("Constructor UserDialogComponent START");
      console.log(dialogRef);
      this.dialogRef = dialogRef; // delete this line
      console.log("Constructor UserDialogComponent END");
     }
```